# Is there some way to rollback redis data after finish java test code?

Tags: java, testing, redis

Is there some way to rollback the data in redis after test code run.
I worked on a java web project using spring boot 2.

I know redis does not provided rollback operation.

So using another redis (like some embedded redis) in test can ensure test code does not change the redis data. And make a mocked redis client to get data   in test redis first and if no data then get from the origin Redis.
Does it workable?

And is there a ready made package implements this function?

Or has any simpler way to rollback?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should be clear on terms. Either you are doing a *real* (narrow) unit test, then you absolutely **decouple** your code under test from any "real" resource, such as databases or file systems or remote servers. In other words: then you mock out such dependencies.

Otherwise, you are doing *functional* testing. And there are simply too many options to give a meaningful answer here. One example would be [Redis Mock](https://dzone.com/articles/java-redis-mock).

But as said: the real answer is that you get clear on your requirements. You should do unit-tests that mock out on a lower level, directly at the (single) class under test.

Comment: ok,it is functional test.The link Redis Mock i have read before.It provide an empty embedded redis when test code run,but I want to get the data that already exits in redis,just not change data in redis after test finish.

Comment: @Yeezh To address that, I would try to "isolate" a redis into some sort of docker container for example. In other words: create a test infrastructure that can easily be pulled up (repeatedly) without much effort, giving a well known state to start with, to then, after testing, be simply disposed as a whole.